# Invalid or NULL argument for object_id []

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call a function and store the result in a varabile

```
la_object_names fls_varchar_table := fls_varchar_table();
la_children_EASs FLS_NUMBER_TABLE         := FLS_NUMBER_TABLE();
loa_objects_EASs ims_api.typo_ims_objects := ims_api.typo_ims_objects(NULL);

la_object_names     := rm.sri_object_utils.get_object_names(pia_object_ids => la_children_EASs);
```

`fls_varchar_table` and `FLS_NUMBER_TABLE` are table of varchar and number declared in a ddl.
`get_object_names` function returns a `fls_varchar_table`

The intialization of `la_children_EASs`

`la_children_EASs.extend(loa_objects_EASs.ims_objects.LAST);`

I think there is an implicit conversion from `fls_number_table` to `ims_api.typo_ims_objects` but not viceversa

I'm getting this error:

> Invalid or NULL argument for object_id [] in procedure/function
>   rm.sri_object_utils.get_object_name

I tried to give and hard coded argument to `get_object_names` method something like this:

```
la_object_names     := rm.sri_object_utils.get_object_names(pia_object_ids => FLS_NUMBER_TABLE(31231,2313213,231231));
```

This returns the expected results. Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you pass parameter of wrong type to this function in first case.
In first case you pass la_children_EASs which is FLS_NUMBER_TABLE(),
in second case you pass fls_varchar_table.

Comment: I don't see changes - the same fls_varchar_table in second case.
Function specification and full error stack will help to answer your question.

Comment: By the way, you declare la_children_EASs but pass as a parameter la_children_EANs
Is this a typo, or you miss la_children_EANs declaration in you example?

Comment: I was debugging and copied the wrong code, now should be right, will check the full stack and come back, thank you